# Reading .txt data to Matlab

Tags: matlab, import, text-files

I am trying to read data from this .txt:

```
obiekt.DEF


Timeplot
Column01: P abs h01 L1 [W]
Column02: P abs h01 L2 [W]
Column03: P abs h01 L3 [W]
Column04: P abs h01 Sum [W]

Time                         Column01    Column02    Column03    Column04
11.03.2004 09:17:02              23500       19812       21529    64,84e+3
11.03.2004 09:17:05              23316       19789       21519    64,62e+3
11.03.2004 09:17:08              23207       19759       21392    64,36e+3
```

I only need data from column: 01,02,03. Some data have ',' instead '.'. How to change it? I have many file like this. I tried this function, but it write all data to one variable.

```
b=textread('test.txt','%s','delimiter',' ','whitespace',' ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use textscan:

```
filename='myfile.txt';
fid=fopen(filename,'r');
data=textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%s%s%s%*s','HeaderLines',10,'CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fid);
data=strrep(data{1},',','.');
data=cellfun(@str2num, data);
```

Setting `HeaderLines` sets the first 10 lines to be ignored. Setting `CollectOutput` groups items of the same type into a cell array (so we get 3 columns of strings). The formatspec `'%*s%*s%s%s%s%*s'` ignores the date, time and Column04 and converts Column01-03 to strings. Then `strrep` replaces the commas with periods. `cellfun` calls `str2num` on each cell and converts the string to a number.

Comment: Works perfectly, but when I open another file, I got [error](http://imgur.com/xzvAXdZ)

Comment: I can't access your link at the moment (internet restrictions), could you update your question with the details of the error and the file that produces it?

Comment: I just checked out your image and updated my answer, it should be the right idea, but I can't test it until the morning. I'll update it if it isn't right.

Comment: I've updated the answer after testing it this morning. Hopefully that's got it now.